# 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'b'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I keep getting this error and I have checked my code several times to find a solution but to no avail.

```
private void PopulateotherNames()
{
    string query = "SELECT a nickName FROM otherNames a" +
                   "INNER JOIN nameNicki b ON a.Id = b.otherNamesId" +
                   "WHERE b.realNameId=@realNameId";

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@realNameId", listRealName.SelectedValue);

        DataTable NickNameTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(NickNameTable);

        listNickName.DisplayMember = "nickName";
        listNickName.ValueMember = "Id";
        listNickName.DataSource = NickNameTable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out... Missing your alias and no spaces in some places. Look into stored procedures and you wouldn't have any of these kinds of problems.

```
string query = "SELECT a.nickName FROM otherNames a " +
        "INNER JOIN nameNicki b ON " +
        "a.Id = b.otherNamesId" +
        " WHERE b.realNameId=@realNameId";
```